# How to do SSR when using laravel and react?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, server-side-rendering

I made a spa project, which use laravel as backend and react as frontend. Now I wondering how to do the server side render?

I only find this way to do ssr, is there other way to do ssr at laravel?

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering

Or can I do SSR using express? the structure would be like following:

**backend api: laravel**

**SSR: express**

**frontend: react**

Is this structure possible?

Comment: Laravel will have nothing to do with  SSR of your react app. Set up your express SSR as you would normally. The API returned by Laravel will not be in your way and can be served from a different server (or domain or neither) entirely.

Comment: @devk Thanks man, you show me the right direction to do the ssr.
I'm trying to do the isomorphic but still have some question. Would you mind to solve my new question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53826283/how-to-use-react-component-with-rendertostring-method

Comment: It has been close to a year since I've last written React code, I can't really help you with that :/

Comment: @devk Ok, still thanks for your help.